# VLC won't play most of my file formats

Tags: sound, video, vlc

first time poster on here, on and off Linux user over the last 20 years.

Running 64bit Ubuntu 15.10, downloaded the latest VLC from the Software Center (2.2.1-3), also found out that I needed to download the ubuntu-restricted-extras for extra codecs, so I did that as well (and rebooted.)

Most of my videos are in either avi, mp4 or wmv format. The default Videos app can play them all perfectly, full sound, full video. What it *can't* do (and one reason I like VLC so much), is scrub through to different parts, so I'm forced to watch the entire thing if I want to see a certain part. (I use VLC on my Mac, and it works flawlessly with all of these videos.)

What VLC on Ubuntu is doing:

- It won't even play avi or wmv files.
- It *plays* mp4 files, but with *no* sound and *no* video. So basically a black screen, but I can scrub through to different parts.
- It also will play the few .flv movies I have with sound and audio - the only format it seems to recognize right now.

What I've done:

- Checked VLC to make sure all audio is not disabled (sound is definitely on throughout the system)
- Downloaded and installed the ubuntu-restricted extras (it does seem to have an issue with the Microsoft Truetype fonts, as though there's something missing, but that shouldn't have anything to do with the audio/video issues.)
- Gstreamer plugins are installed (looks like it includes support for wavpack and quicktime as well.)
- And I have looked all around online for this problem, but I've only seen maybe 1-2 instances where it won't play audio *or* video, most issues are either one or the other.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

```
  -Bryan
```

Comment: can you specify more about the hardware on which Ubuntu is running?

Comment: It's running on my older 2011 Mac Mini hardware:
Intel Core i5-2415M 2.30Ghz x 4
Intel Sandybridge Mobile graphics

Until I got my new Mac, I was running OS X on here with all these same videos/VLC, so the hardware is definitely capable of doing it.

Comment: yes, so it seems...... I think it might be just an init package or something... have you tried installing older VLC releases? http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, will uninstall VLC from software center and try a slightly older version.

Comment: I tried loading the older version, but I still have the same problem...VLC is usually so effortless to "just work". I remember it working on my last Ubuntu, which I think was around the 12.x series.

Comment: That does sound strange.... I tried setting up the same - Ubuntu 15 and vlc 2.2 - and works fine here.... Also - tried to simulate your hardware on a virtual machine - and with the same setup it also works fine..... Assuming you mostly play common codecs - I don't see any reason for using the ubuntu-restricted-extras. I can't really tell the connection between that package, your apple hardware, and the problem - but with nothing to lose - try uninstalling all and just using a common "as-is" setting - meaning, just run Ubuntu with VLC - no added packages...

Comment: And also - do you recall sending your Mac for a custom hardware installation or something of the likes?

Comment: I did reinstall Ubuntu with 14.04, and just loaded VLC by itself - that made the mp4s play with *video* (yay), but no luck on the audio for some reason. So I literally just reinstalled 15.10 a little while ago (because I'd like to keep a more up to date version), and I'm about to download VLC without any extras and see how that goes. 

When I reinstalled this time, I noticed something during the install that didn't happen the first time, so maybe something's different. I redownloaded a brand new iso also, in case the first was corrupted, so will report back in a bit.

Comment: And no, there's absolutely no custom hardware. The only upgrades I made were adding RAM (so 16gb in this machine), and a 480gb SSD (only drive, makes rebooting almost instant (10 seconds or so.)

Comment: Well it looks like that fixed it :) Didn't need to download the extras, worked perfectly, like it should've the first time. Seems something may have gotten corrupted in the process of creating the USB stick.

Thanks for giving me some ideas along the way, happily using Linux again :)

Comment: glad to hear - I'll post as an answer for developer's info ;) and if that solved the issue - mark the answer for others

Answer (score 0):

Do you recall sending your Mac for a custom hardware installation or something of the likes?... though I don't think that's the issue here.

It seems that the integration of the two wasn't perfect. Maybe a corrupted USB stick or something similar.

Since you're mostly using common codecs, there's no need for extra packages to be installed, and maybe that's the problem.

Try uninstalling all and reinstalling using a common "as-is" setting - meaning, just run Ubuntu 15 with VLC 2.2 - no added packages.